# My firebase addvalueeventlistener is actioned when the containing activity is not opened

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-lifecycle

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private Query getChatsList;
private ValueEventListener getChatsListEventListener;
private AdapterChatsList adapterChatsList;
private List<String> providerUids;
private List<String> providerNames;
private RecyclerView chatsRecyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chats_list);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    providerUids = new ArrayList<>();
    providerNames = new ArrayList<>();

    chatsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatsRecyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatsListActivity.this);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    chatsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    getChatsList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Chats").orderByChild("details/lastInteraction");
    getChatsListEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            providerUids.clear(); providerNames.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String providerUid = ds.getKey();
                String providerName = ds.child("details").child("oppositeName").getValue(String.class);


                providerUids.add(providerUid);
                providerNames.add(providerName);

                adapterChatsList = new AdapterChatsList(ChatsListActivity.this, providerUids, providerNames);
                adapterChatsList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                chatsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChatsList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getChatsList.addValueEventListener(getChatsListEventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(getChatsListEventListener != null) {
        getChatsList.removeEventListener(getChatsListEventListener);
    }
}
```

My firebase addvalueeventlistener is actioned when the containing activity is not opened. I open my app's home activity where a button links to the questioned activity. If a change in the firebase is made the home activity refreshes. If I have opened the activity containing the value event listener and a firebase change occurs, the activity is closed and the app goes back to Home activity. I have set the event listener for the database reference in the onStart() and I am removing it in the onStop(). What can I do?

Comment: use `addChildEventListener`

Comment: And what should be the function in it (onChildAdded or)

Comment: It does not work again.

Comment: Using a child listener will make no difference to this problem. At first glance the code looks correct, although you might want to check if your `onStop` is actually being called. If not, consider removing the listener in `onPause` instead.

Comment: what i can think of problem may be cause by this line `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser()... ` it think u should create a root ref or ref to `Users` node and then add child to that node like this  userRef.child(uid).child("chat") .